# Разбиение плоскости по типу диаграммы Вороного

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия, glsl, шейдеры, вороной

Ищу алгоритм похожий на диаграмму Вороного, который так же, используя множество заданных точек, разбивает плоскость только на треугольгики произвольной формы?

[image]

Задача написать простой fragment шейдер по подобию скажем [этого](http://glslsandbox.com/e#33351.0), но только с треугольниками (полигонами).

Безусловно, можно к примеру "приделать" триангуляцию Делоне, но может быть есть что-то попроще?

Comment: http://netlib.org/voronoi/ для справки

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Диаграмма Вороного в принципе не может состоять "только из треугольников". Так о каком "похожий на диаграмму Вороного" идет речь? В чем вы тут ожидаете сходство с диаграммой Вороного? В триангуляции Делоне исходные точки являются *вершинами* триангуляции. В диаграмме Вороного исходные точки, наоборот, лежат *внутри* регионов разбиения. Так что именно вам нужно: "вершинами" или "внутри"?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется ничего проще нет. Если вы ищете алгортим, похожий на "вороновский", то значит,  сложность построения диаг.В. вас примерно устраивает :) Так вот постройте д.В. и перейдите к смежной структуре, получите почти триангуляцию Делоне, останется лишь очевидным образом разбить на треугольники полигоны, в которых больше 3х вершин